# How to duplicate the database in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I need to duplicate the existing database including its schema and structure to another new database. I need this in shell command environment and not in pgadmin. Please kindly help me.

```
nohup pg_dump exampledb > example-01.sql
createdb -O postgres exampledbclone_01
```

my user is "postgres"

```
nohup psql exampledbclone_01 < example-01.sql
```

```
$ pg_dump mydb > db.sql
$ psql -d newdb -f db.sql
```

Answer (score 61):

If you want to duplicate it within the same PostgreSQL install and you don't have actively connected users there's a handy shortcut:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_new_database TEMPLATE my_old_database;
```

or from the shell

```
createdb -T my_old_database my_new_database;
```

Otherwise you'll need to use `pg_dump`, `createdb` and `pg_restore`, e.g.

```
pg_dump -Fc -f olddb.pgdump -d olddb &&\
createdb newdb &&\
pg_restore -d newdb olddb.pgdump
```

If you're using `nohup` so the command doesn't die if you lose your ssh session, consider using `screen` instead.

Comment: Awesome `CREATE DATABASE my_new_database TEMPLATE my_old_database;`

Comment: Brilliant! It not just copy structure, but also data!

Comment: @Foton Yep, though you can use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` if you want to be more selective and dump (say) just the structure.

Comment: Any idea how long this should take for a 1 TB database? It's been going for about an hour already for me..

Comment: @Vincent Depends mainly on your system's I/O

Comment: For me, it finished after about 12 hours.

Comment: Beautiful. Postgres is so easy. I have a recreate-test-db script with two lines: `dropdb xxx_test; createdb -T xxx_development xxx_test`

Answer (score 8):

Postgres allows the use of any existing database on the server as a template when creating a new database. I'm not sure whether pgAdmin gives you the option on the create database dialog but you should be able to execute the following in a query window if it doesn't:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE originaldb OWNER dbuser;
```

Still, you may get:

> ERROR:  source database "originaldb" is being accessed by other users

To disconnect all other users from the database, you can use this query:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'originaldb' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```